# Responsibility sharing in a global organisation

Tags: management

I work for a company which has units across the world. I work in the IT department as a Group Lead, managing multiple teams out of India. I have IT and other counterpart leads to collaborate with across the world. From a team size perspective, the total number of associates in India is the largest. Most other countries have smaller local teams, mainly comprising of senior management and specialised roles. For eg. If the team size in India is 100, the team size in other countries will be less than 5. Naturally most of the operational work is done from India for global projects, with local teams playing project management roles.

However, the distribution of work is currently ad-hoc. I wanted to know if I could find a standard approach for division of responsibilities in such a setup. Is there a generally accepted way of going about and assigning responsibilities? Can tools like the RACI matrix help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Size doesn't always matter, it's more about who has the control. I know companies who's head office is the smallest in terms of staff, but has the last word in everything to do with how the business is run.

In terms of international communications and logistics the normal way I have seen it done is just handed out from head office. If there are issues then usually a proposal is made and either agreed to by the bosses and forced on everyone, or there is some discussion with all affected. But at the end of the day it's usually a single office making the decision whether or not to implement changes.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the reply. I wanted to understand if I could draft a methodology-based responsibility sharing system. Primarily as an exercise to see if I could be doing things better. For e.g. Can I say that activity X which impacts Country A, will be done by the central team, project managed by Country A and accountability shared between A and central team.  The aim of the exercise was purely to improve systems using a validated/standard methodology.

Comment: Most if not all project management systems allow things to be broken into spheres of interest and overlapping groups. It's just a matter of assigning leaders to groups and projects I would think. No need to reinvent the wheel